# Render File on S3 using Meteor

Tags: amazon-web-services, meteor, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, iron-router

I'm trying to render a PDF (`but this question can applied to an Image file or any type of file you would render to a web browser`) to the browser with Meteor 1.0.3, Iron Router (IR), using S3 as the storage location of the pdf.

### Context

I have this process working without S3, only using a server side directory, but would now like to incorporate S3 for storage.

I currently have my generated file located here for example:

> application-name/server/.files/users/user-name/test.pdf

I use IR on a server side path to render the pdf like so:

```
Router.route('/test-pdf', function() {
  if(!user) return this.response.end("Not allowed");

  var filePath = process.env.PWD + "/server/.files/users/" + userId + "/" + "test.pdf";
  console.log(filePath);
  var fs = Npm.require('fs');
  var data = fs.readFileSync(filePath);
  this.response.write(data);
  this.response.end();
}, {name: 'test-pdf', where: 'server'});
```

### Packages

I looked at using `Lepozepo/S3` or even `eluck/meteor-aws-sdk`, but haven't decided based on what I know at the moment.

In particular, `Lepozepo/S3`, seems to dedicated to S3, so I'm leaning this way for now.

`Lepozepo/S3` seems simple enough to set up, but I'm not sure how to use it to '*get*' or '*stream*' the file from S3 and render it to the browser correctly.

I see in `Lepozepo/S3` API calls to 'stream', 'upload', and 'delete', but no real examples of what seems to be what I need, which would be I think either 'stream' or download.

### Question

How can I render a PDF (or another type of file) to the browser using `Lepozepo/S3` API calls using a IR route in Meteor?

Comment: for browser to render it correctly, you will need to set the header `mime-type` of uploaded file to `application/pdf`

Comment: @ajduke, thanks for the comment.  What  do you mean?  I can render the pdf with Iron Router without doing all this header/mime-type stuff -- why is having the pdf in S3 any different?  How does changing the source, change the way I render?